# Having trouble with GREP and REGEX

Tags: regex, linux, grep, file-search

I have a text file that stores combinations of four numbers in the following format:

```
Num1,Num2,Num3,Num4
Num5,Num6,Num7,Num8
.............
```

I have a whole bunch of such files and what I need is to grep for all filenames that contains the pattern described above.

I constructed my grep as follows:

```
grep -l "{d+},{d+},{d+},{d+}" /some/path/to/file/name
```

The grep terminates without returning anything.

Can somebody point out what I might be doing wrong with my grep statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
egrep -l '[[:digit:]]+,[[:digit:]]+,[[:digit:]]+,[[:digit:]]+' /some/path/to/file/name
```

Comment: Great! It works. Do you by any chance know what is wrong with the syntax I used?

Comment: `{d+}` does not mean *match any number with at least one digit*. That would be `\d+` in *perl* type regexps (grep -P). `[0-9]+` or `[[:digit:]]+` means the same using *extended* regexps (grep -E, egrep). Using *basic* regexps (grep) you could use `[0-9][0-9]*` to get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

One way is using a `perl` regexp:

```
grep -Pl "\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+" /some/path/to/file/name
```

In your syntax `d` is literal. It should be escaping that letter, but is not accepted by `grep` regular regexp.

Answer (score -1):

I've ended up with this without any other options (`grep -P` wasn't working for me)

`grep "\d\+,\d\+,\d\+,\d\+"`

Somehow more characters has to be escaped using grep regex.